# LongClick textView, clickable link

Tags: android

I am writing an app that has a ListView of text. In each row there is a combination of text and links. I added an OnItemLongClickListener to the list and made the links clickable with

```
my_text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

The problem is, if I am able to click the link, I cannot get the textView to register the LongClick.

I have tried different methods to make the links clickable such as

```
android:autoLink="web
```

But this doesn't make the links clickable.

My question is: Is there a different way that I should set the LongClickListener, or a different way to make the links clickable?

Has anyone else encountered a similar problem?

I should note that right now the OnItemLongClickListener makes the links register the LongClicks but this causes a problem when a textview doesnt have a link or a user tries to longClick somewhere else in the view (besides the link)

Code:
I programatically inflate a relativeLayout containing a list view and add it to a view flipper:

RelativeLayout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/my_list"
        style="@style/listViewSimple"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#f9f9f9"
        android:cacheColorHint="#00000000"
        android:divider="#ccc"
        android:dividerHeight="1px"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp"
        android:footerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="false"
        android:persistentDrawingCache="none" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Adding everything programatically:

```
            RelativeLayout list = (RelativeLayout) LayoutInflater.from(MyActivity.this).inflate(R.layout.my_list_layout, null);
            vf.addView(list);
            ListView lv = (ListView) list.findViewById(R.id.my_list);
            lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(listLongListener);
```

Making Links clickable(in getView() of adapte):

```
        my_tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(formatted_text)));
        my_tv.setLinkTextColor(linkColor);
        my_tv.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This makes links clickable but seems consume all clicks before they get to the textview. I tried to add a longClickListener that returns false but that didn't seem to have any affect.

My temporary fix is to set a itemLongClickListener and an onItemClickListener to the listItem and just display a dialog with the clickable text in onListItemClick. This works but adds an extra click for users to interact with the text

Comment: Can you tell me what you need the longclick for? I get that clicking on the link will open it in a webview. Do you have a requirement that on clicking of the item in the list, it opens another activity with its details?

Comment: I use the long click to open a dialog of options for the user that takes them to different activities depending on which listItem was clicked.

Comment: Can you add the code where u have currently put the OnItemLongClickListener() and the part where you make the link clickable? Also provide the xml containing your list and the one containing ure list item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My temporary fix is to set a onItemLongClickListener and an onItemClickListener to the listItem and just display a dialog with the clickable text in onItemClick. This works but adds an extra click for users to interact with the text.

If a better answer is posted I will change selected answer

Answer (score 2):

I would create a custom Adapter, set your ListView to use that Adapter, and then in getView, set a View.OnClickListener on the TextView that has your text and a View.OnLongClickListener on the TextView that has your link.  Remove the existing listeners you referred in your question so that they don't conflict.

Comment: Hey louie! Thanks for the advice but I think I wasn't clear. I need the entire view to be able to register the longClick, and the view contains an image, and several textviews. I want for a link to be clickable, but on Longclick I display a dialog with a list of options for users. The dialog should appear whether the user longclicked the image, the text, or some whitespace. I have a 'row' defined in xml that contains the list items, and i would prefer if they could longClick anywhere in the row